# How do I specify parameters dependent on each other in ARM template?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I want to provide an option for parameter to either use `2016-Datacenter-with-Containers` ImageSku from `WindowsServer` offer or `Datacenter-Core-1709-with-Containers-smalldisk` from `WindowsServerSemiannual` offer. How I can limit user via parameter to choose either one since those are dependent on each other for VM profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those are your only two options, use allowedValues in the parameter definition and then use an if() statement for the publisher/offer -- based on the parameter value.  Something like this:

```
        "windowsOSVersion": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "2016-Datacenter-with-Containers",
        "allowedValues": [
            "2016-Datacenter-with-Containers",
            "Datacenter-Core-1709-with-Containers-smalldisk"
        ]
    }
```

And then:

```
                    "imageReference": {
                    "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
                    "offer": "[if(contains(parameters('windowsOSVersion'), '2016'),'WindowsServer', 'WindowsServerSemiAnnual')]",
                    "sku": "[parameters('windowsOSVersion')]",
                    "version": "latest"
                },
```

You could use equals instead of contains for more robustness.